# Unsupported Media Type al mandar POST en Flutter

Tags: json, post, http, flutter, dart

Hola muy buenas a todos.

Tengo un problema al hacer una petición HTTP POST en Flutter. Intento mandar un JSON (tal como acepta el backend) para hacer una insercion en BBDD. El problema es el siguiente:

```
statusCode = 415
reasonPhrase = "Unsupported Media Type"
```

Estoy trabajando con clases que luego convierto a Map para poder mandarlas pero no funciona. También he vuelvo a convertir a JSON ese Map para hacer la prueba pero sigue fallando.

He intentado varias pruebas sin solucionar este problema. Quizá se me escapa algo.

```
class Incidencia {
  final String  EntidadCentroDestinoId;
  final String  GestionEnumId;
  final String  DetalleGestionEnumId;
  final String  EntidadAlumnoId;
  final String  Descripcion;

  Incidencia({this.EntidadCentroDestinoId, this.GestionEnumId, this.DetalleGestionEnumId, this.EntidadAlumnoId, this.Descripcion,});

  Map toMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["EntidadCentroDestinoId"] = EntidadCentroDestinoId;
    map["GestionEnumId"] = GestionEnumId;
    map["DetalleGestionEnumId"] = DetalleGestionEnumId;
    map["EntidadAlumnoId"] = EntidadAlumnoId;
    map["Descripcion"] = Descripcion;

    return map;
  }
}
```

El botón que hace la petición:

```
            FlatButton(
                child: Text('Enviar'),
                color: Colors.deepOrange,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                onPressed: () => {
                  incidencia  = new Incidencia(
                    Descripcion: myController.text,
                    DetalleGestionEnumId: detalleGestionEnumId,
                    EntidadAlumnoId: entidadAlumnoId,
                    EntidadCentroDestinoId: "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                    GestionEnumId: gestionEnumId,
                  ),

                  iSV.insertarIncidencia(incidencia: incidencia.toMap()).then((res) => {
                      print(res),
                      Navigator.pop(context),
                  }),
                } //aqui ira la llamada al metodo future post para guardar la incidencia
            ),
```

Y este el Service:

```
Future insertarIncidencia({Map incidencia}) async {
    String jsonmapaIncidencia = jsonEncode(incidencia);
    var url = Uri.parse('http://unadireccion.com/api/metodo');
    var retu =http.post(
       url, 
       body: jsonmapaIncidencia,
    );

    return retu;
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo probaste desde Postman? agregaste los headers de content type applicaton/json?

Answer (score 0):

Correcto @ diegoveloper desde postman tampoco lo mandaba. El problema parece ser que los headers son fuertemente tipados y hay que enviarlo con mayusculas incluidas. Además al convertir en JSON me estaba creando un Mapa (no deberia)... Añadiendo:

```
headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept" : "application/json"}
```

y asegurandome que mi variable es JSON, lo manda sin problema

Comment: listo, solo no te olvides que te faltó el `await` antes del `http.post`

Comment: También me dí cuenta @diegoveloper ahora el código es este `http.Response retu = await http.post( url, body: inci, headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept" : "application/json, text/plain" }, );` muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
/metodo para crear un usuariod
```

hola me disculpan por aca esto este metodo para crear un usuario en dynamoDB AWS al principio me creaba en usuario hasta hace poco dejo de hacerlo... con su respuesta vacia y estado de respusta 200 OK
la peticiones GET PUT funcionan normal
Future createUser(UserModel user) async {
//obtengo tok en del usuario

```
try {
  crearteUser = true;
  notifyListeners();
  final tem = await userId(); //obtengo id del usuariox-www-form-urlencoded
  final token = await userToken();
  user.id = tem;
  user.email = _credentials!.username;
  print(user.toJson());
  final url = Uri.https(_baseUrl, '/user');
  final response = await http.post(
    url,
    body: user.toJson(),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': token,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print(response.body);
    NotificationsService.showSnackbar(response.body);
    if (response.bodyBytes.isNotEmpty) {
      NotificationsService.showSnackbar(response.body + ' Inicia Sesion');
      final state = AuthState(
          authFlowStatus: AuthFlowStatus
              .session); //prueba de la pantalla de verificacion
      authStateController.add(state);
    }
    crearteUser = false;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  crearteUser = false;
  notifyListeners();
} on Exception catch (e) {
  print('error en post2: ' + e.toString());
  NotificationsService.showSnackbar(e.toString());
  crearteUser = false;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

}

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta o una nueva pregunta? Por favor, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.